# Timer in Service

Tags: android

I'm making an Android service which has a `Timer` inside it. My plan is to do some tasks every 30 minutes or so. My question is how to handle the timer object when the service is being killed by the OS due to low memory?

So, should I put the `timer.schedule(...)` code inside `onCreate` or inside `onStartCommand`? And what happens to the timer object when the service is stopped by the OS? I've did some research and it seems that there is no callback for service termination on low memory.

Comment: You should probably use an [alarm](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).  Your description doesn't suggest a reason for using a `Service`, and there's almost never a good reason to use a `Timer` on Android.

Comment: Agreed. `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` are *much* better solutions here. Only have a `Service` running when [it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Sitting and watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user. `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler` allow you to keep your service stopped (except perhaps when doing the scheduled work), keeping your process at normal importance, and letting Android better manage memory for the user.

Comment: I actually want to collect data from sensors and do some calculation. Is Alarm and JobScheduler fits this scenario?

Comment: yes AlarmManager will serve your purpose. Create a thread in your Service so that UI of your app wont block